# How to fetch data from API in Flutter Tree View

Tags: flutter, api, dart, treeview

I have created this Flutter Tree View, but I am not understanding how can I take the data from API and show it in tree view just like I have shown in the pictures below, I want to achieve exactly the same result as shown in the pictures below.

For instance, if I check the checkbox of a parent, then its children and its grand-children and great grand-children must be selected, But If I select only the parent's child then its children and great grand-children must be selected:

I have attached my code below.
Please guide. Thanks!

The one I have created (static data):

[image: The one I created]

What I want to achieve:

(1)

[image: Achieve 1]

(2)

[image: Achieve 2]

Model:

```
class TreeModel {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? displayName;
  int? digits;
  String? category;
  List<String>? alliases;
  String? latestAllias;

  TreeModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.displayName,
    this.digits,
    this.category,
    this.alliases,
    this.latestAllias,
  });

  TreeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    displayName = json['displayName'];
    digits = json['digits'];
    category = json['category'];
    if (json['alliases'] != null) {
      alliases = List<String>.from(
          json['alliases'].map((dynamic alias) => alias.toString()));
    } else {
      alliases = null;
    }
    latestAllias = json['latestAllias']?.toString();
  }
}
```

HomeScreen:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:flutter_simple_treeview/flutter_simple_treeview.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:pluton_test/app/data/constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:pluton_test/app/data/constants/app_typography.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' as rootBundle;
import 'package:pluton_test/app/models/tree_model.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Flutter Tree",
          style: AppTypography.kBold16.copyWith(color: AppColors.kPrimaryColor),
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppColors.kWhiteColor,
        elevation: 0,
        leadingWidth: 0,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.w),
          child: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: AppColors.kBlackColor),
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.w),
            child: const Icon(Icons.person, color: AppColors.kBlackColor),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.h, horizontal: 20.w),
            height: Get.height * 0.25,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: AppColors.kPrimaryColor,
            child: Text(
              "Please choose an Investment target",
              style:
                  AppTypography.kBold14.copyWith(color: AppColors.kWhiteColor),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
              child: Container(
                height: 400.h,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.kWhiteColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.r),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                      spreadRadius: 3,
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    FutureBuilder(
                      future: ReadJsonData(),
                      builder: (context, data) {
                        if (data.hasError) {
                          return Center(child: Text("${data.error}"));
                        } else if (data.hasData) {
                          return TreeView(
                            nodes: [
                              TreeNode(
                                content: const Text("Docs"),
                                children: [
                                  TreeNode(content: const Text("Text 1")),
                                  TreeNode(content: const Text("Text 2")),
                                  TreeNode(content: const Text("Text 3"))
                                ],
                              ),
                              TreeNode(
                                content: const Text("Docs"),
                                children: [
                                  TreeNode(content: const Text("Text 1")),
                                  TreeNode(content: const Text("Text 2")),
                                  TreeNode(content: const Text("Text 3"))
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.w),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: AppColors.kPrimaryColor,
                          fixedSize: Size(Get.width, 20.h),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text("Next"),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<TreeModel>> ReadJsonData() async {
    final jsonData =
        await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString("jsonfile/response.json");
    final list = json.decode(jsonData) as List<dynamic>;
    return list.map((e) => TreeModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
}
```